# Product with a maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group and $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$. If $N$ is a subgroup $G$ not contained in $M$, then $G=MN$.

I know $M \subseteq MN$. I want to use the maximality of $M$ but $MN$ is not a subgroup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true. Consider for example $G = S_3$ and $M < G$ a subgroup of order $2$. If $N$ is any other subgroup of order $2$, then $N$ is not contained in $M$ and $MN \neq G$.

The problem here is that $MN$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: Excelent counter example. +1